# Need Pop up screen or custom alert in phone gap

Tags: cordova

is there any way to make custom alert or popup screen in phonegap .actually i want to make alert which have 3 row (example).on clicking the first row it will show description of that row (by expanding  the length). but on clicking the second row it will close the description of first row and open the description of second row .

can you please help me?

Comment: I don't know if this will help... but if you use jQuery Mobile, I think you may wanna have a look at jQuery Mobile Dialogs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

Comment: No sir i need some think like table , on row  clicking it will expand or on clicking other row expanding row will close and new row will open

Comment: The thing is, jQuery Mobile Dialog provides the pop up effect thing, and I think you could add the table. What do you think? :S

Comment: actually sir i am  beginner , i always used java script intend of jquery  (for easier understand).can you have any simple share it..

Comment: you can achieve this with plain HTML, CSS3 and jQuery (I´m afraid sooner or later you should have a peak at the framework). Have you googled before? I think nobody will just code it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show just an alert you can use just JavaScript: alert();

For customized alerts you can use a plugin like SimpleModal:

http://simplemodal.plasm.it/

If you need an advanced customization you can try ShadowBox:

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/